# How to determine i+++--j in C

Tags: c

In C,

```
int i = 20;
int j = 5;
int k = i+++--j;
```

Why is k=24?

In my understanding, k = (i)++ + (--j) so it is (20 + 4)++ = 25.

OK. Here is a little programme I wrote for test, and yes the post increment is done after k is assigned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 20;
    int k = i++;
    printf("%d\n", k);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20
21
```

Could anyone tell me why vote down? I was unsure about this because I was a new commer to C.

Comment: <del>undefined behaviour</del>

Comment: @bolov No, it isn't.

Comment: `k = (i++) + (--j)` == 24

Comment: Just to be clear, `i++` evaluates to 20, and `--j` evaluates to 4. `k` is now 24, `i` is now 21, and `j` is now 4.

Comment: No, I think this one is defined, no variables are reused in the expression. I post increments, after the statement, J predecrements, before the assignment. So 20+4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as a **greedy algorithm**, it will take as many characters as possible, if they make sense.

Example:

```
i+   // good, keep going
i++  // good, keep going
i+++ // not good, start new token
+    // good, keep going
+-   // not valid, start new token
-    // good
--   // good
--j  // valid
```

So:

```
int i = 20;
int j = 5;
int k = i++ + --j; // (20++) + (--5)
```

That is how it is grouped. The second part is pre and post increment.

```
i++ // post-increment, use the value first and then increment
--j // pre-increment, decrement first and then use the value
```

So you get:

```
int k = 20 + 4
// afterwards: i = 21 and j = 4
```

Comment: I don't think the greedy algorithm part is necessary, but the post/pre increment part is the most important part. Thanks givanse

Answer (score 5):

C has a famous rule of *maximal munch strategy*.
From this rule:

```
i+++--j
```

is parsed as

```
(i++) + (--j)
```

> (C99, 6.4p4) "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing       tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token."

And of course the value of `i++` is `i` and the value of `--j` is `j - 1`, so the value of `i+++--j` is `20 + 4` equal to `24`.

Comment: you are correct, the error of the asker was to increment k which is 24.

Answer (score 2):

> In my understanding, `k = (i)++ + (--j)`

Yes, that's it.

> so it is (20 + 4)++ = 25.

No, it's 20 + 4 and so it is 24. (You can't increment a constant, nor does it make any sense, **nor is there a second increment operator in the expression,** so I really don't know where you got that idea). But otherwise your deduction is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what others have said as far as parsing. By the way, when faced with questions such as this operator precedence can be very important. For C, [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) has a list of operators and their precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The value of k is determined by the operators precedence.

The difference bitween `n = i++` and `n = ++i`, is that in the first the value is of `i` is assigned to n before the incrementation, but in the last the value of `i` is assigned to n after the incrementation.

In the case of `k = i++ + --j`. the operations are processed in this order:

```
1) decrement j by 1 (j = j-1)
2) assign i + j to k (k = i + j)
3) increment i by 1 (i = i + 1)
```